Indirect relationships in Lavaan R
Are my results of a bootstrapped indirect effect within a multilevel sem model reliable in case the upper value of the 95% CI is higher then one:

monteCarloCI(FactorA, standardized=TRUE, reps=20000)

           est.std ci.lower ci.upper

indirectrcw   -0.017   -0.066    0.024
indirectssiw   0.043    0.005    0.104
indirectssfw   0.058    0.011    0.121
indirecttsw    0.049   -0.052    0.151
indirectrcb   -0.108   -0.509    0.207
indirectssib   0.414    0.247    0.584
indirectssfb   0.605    0.284    1.025
indirecttsb    0.257    0.100    0.392
Should I include direct relationships in the path model to conclude on the indirect relationships if I have no hypotheses on that? e.g. from "form_comm" and "inform_comm" to "need":
model1 <- '
+

level: 1

form_comm =~ Q8_1 + Q8_2 + Q8_3
inform_comm =~ Q10_1 + Q10_2 + Q10_3
Role_amb =~ Q21_1 + Q21_2 + Q21_3
Soc_Sup =~ Q18_1 + Q18_2 + Q18_3
Task_Sign =~ Q22_1 + Q22_2 + Q22_3
Need =~ Needx + Needy + Needz

Role_amb ~ a*form_comm
Soc_Sup ~ binform_comm + cform_comm
Task_Sign ~ d*form_comm
Need ~ eRole_amb + fSoc_Sup + g*Task_Sign



#Correlations
form_comm ~~ inform_comm
Role_amb ~~ Soc_Sup
Role_amb ~~ Task_Sign
Soc_Sup ~~ Task_Sign


level: 2

form_comm =~ Q8_1 + Q8_2 + Q8_3
inform_comm =~ Q10_1 + Q10_2 + Q10_3
Role_amb =~ Q21_1 + Q21_2 + Q21_3
Soc_Sup =~ Q18_1 + Q18_2 + Q18_3
Task_Sign =~ Q22_1 + Q22_2 + Q22_3
Need =~ Needx + Needy + Needz

Role_amb ~ aa*form_comm
Soc_Sup ~ bbinform_comm + ccform_comm
Task_Sign ~ dd*form_comm
Need ~ eeRole_amb + ffSoc_Sup + gg*Task_Sign


Indirect effect (a*b)

indirectrcw := a*e
indirectssiw := b*f
indirectssfw := c*f
indirecttsw := d*g
indirectrcb:= aa*ee
indirectssib := bb*ff
indirectssfb := cc*ff
indirecttsb := dd*gg


'


FactorA <- sem(model1, data = Daily_Diary_Study_WERKDOC_parcels_CMC_2,



           cluster = "id",



           estimator ="ML",



           # optim.method = "NLMINB",



           fixed.x = FALSE)



I would like to know whether my result is reliable given the high upper bound of the CI interval and whether I should include direct effects to conclude on the indirect effect.

You should provide a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
And here is some help with formatting your syntax better: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Are my results of a bootstrapped indirect effect reliable when the 95% CI is higher than one?

The parametric bootstrap (or Monte Carlo) CI is not invalid just because an upper confidence limit > 1.  It is based on the normal-theory SEs of the estimated parameters, so the method isn't aware of natural boundaries on correlations or variances.  In the case when a confidence limit exceeds a natural boundary, you could interpret it as though the confidence limit is on the boundary.
But standardized multiple-regression slopes are not correlations; only for simple-regression (1 predictor of 1 outcome) does the standardized slope = the correlation. In general, standardized slopes can exceed +/- 1, so there is nothing wrong with your result.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/524878/standardized-bivariate-linear-regression-coefficients-1
